# Multisampled Nearest Filtering in PS 2.0 is it possible?

Tags: shaders, hlsl, antialiasing, filtering

My game involves blocky, pixelated 3D textures. When using nearest neighbor filtering with a texture sampler, I get the desired result of nicely pixelated textures -- with the caveat that hard lines between pixels are aliased. Here's a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

See the jaggies?

I'd like to know if I can use some kind of screen-space multisampling to fix these jagged edges. I'm using HLSL and pixel shader 2.0. Is it possible to accomplish this in the shader? (Note that MSAA does not work in this case because the aliasing is in the texture sampler, not in rasterizing geometry).

Comment: A pure RGB antialiasing method like MLAA or FXAA should do the trick.
http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/gamedev/files/sdk/11/FXAA_WhitePaper.pdf
http://visual-computing.intel-research.net/publications/papers/2009/mlaa/mlaa.pdf
(Note that these are usually implemented in Shader Model 3.0+, but others have reported getting barebones approximations of the techniques working in 2.0)

Comment: Sweet, I found a PS 2.0 FXAA example. I may integrate this into my game and provide an option for switching between FXAA and MSAA. Thanks!